# Logic behind MY factorial function in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I know questions were asked on factorial function in Prolog.I found many codes in the answers provided by people.But my problem is, I have written two codes for fact. The first function is working only for `fact(1,X),fact(2,X),fact(3,X)`.From 4 onwards, it is resulting `false`. I want to know the logic behind this function fact and why it is failing to give result for large numbers.

```
fact(1,1).
fact(N,F):-fact(N1,F1),N is N1+1,F is F1*N,!.

fact1(1,1).
fact1(N,F):-N>1,N1 is N-1,fact1(N1,F1),F is F1*N.

?- fact(2,X).
X = 2.
?- fact(3,X).
X = 6.
?- fact(4,X).
false.
?- fact(5,X).
false.
?- fact(15,X).
false.
```

The fact1 function is giving answers perfectly,

```
?- fact1(5,X).
X = 120 ;
false.

?- fact1(50,X).
X = 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000 ;
```

I would like to know what's wrong with `fact()` function logically.You can also provide slight modifications to `fact()`, making it work.I suspect that it may be because of the cut(`!`),they say it is risky goal in Prolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I know **nothing** about a Prolog predicate, I always ask the system:

## Which solutions are there *at all*?

In terms of Prolog, this means that I ask the **most general** query, where each argument is a fresh variable.

For example, in the case of `fact/2`, I would ask:

```
?- fact(N, F).
```

In this example, I get precisely *2 solutions*:

```
N = F, F = 1 ;
N = F, F = 2.
```

So, the system tells me: There really only are *2 possibilities* for this predicate to hold: one where `N` is 1, and one where `N` is 2.

**On the other hand**, the system also tells me that there is a solution where `N` is 3:

```
?- fact(3, F).
F = 6.
```

So, we may first want to ask:

*Which is it?* Are there 2 solutions or three, or even more??

and, further:

Do we want a predicate that yields **contradicting** answers??

## Consequence: `fact(4, _)` fails

Consider the following **general** skeleton of a predicate:

```
fact(N, F):-
        some_predicate(N1, F1),
        N #= N1+1,
        F #= F1*N,
        ...
```

In your particular case, `some_predicate/2` is `fact/2`. I have *generalized* your concrete snippet to derive a more general explanation and to avoid any confusion that may arise *only because* your concrete case coincidentally involves a *recursive* predicate. The following holds whether or not the predicate is recursive:

If you *know* (as we now do) that `some_predicate/2` **only** has solutions where `N1` is either 1 or 2, then **`N` cannot be 4**.

This explains *logically*, using **purely algebraic** properties of `fact/2`, **why `fact(4, _)` fails**.

Notice in particular that it is *not* necessary to *trace* the execution. Just by using logical reasoning, we have found why your query *cannot hold*.

## Go home `!/0`, you are drunk!

Let us first remove the `!/0` from your version:

```
fact(1, 1).
fact(N, F):-
        fact(N1, F1),
        N #= N1+1,
        F #= F1*N.
```

We observe that this **fixes** the problem:

```
?- fact(N, F).
N = F, F = 1 ;
N = F, F = 2 ;
N = 3,
F = 6 ;
N = 4,
F = 24 ;
etc.
```

**In accordance** with these answers, we also get:

```
?- fact(3, F).
F = 6 .
```

In return, we now get *other* issues, but at least we have avoided a concrete **contradiction** in answers.

I recommend you stick to the pure monotonic core of Prolog to benefit most from the language. Once you leave this subset, reasoning about your programs will become extremely hard, and you will lose the most valuable properties you otherwise almost automatically obtain. See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).